# Electron app is not available for testing with TestFlight

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electronic-signature

Need help with uploading app into testflight 
Now we have “not available for testing” error
Maybe it’s because of “Build Platfoms” field is empty

But if we add macosx platform, we run into these errors ->

1. Asset validation failed
   Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on macOS. Specifically, key 'CFBundleSupportedPlatforms' in ‘… Login Helper.app/…/Login Helper' is not supported
2. Asset validation failed
   Invalid Code Signing Entitlements …. key 'CFBundleSupportedPlatforms' in ‘… appName.app/…/‘appName is not supported.

What's wrong with macosx or else?

Comment: Same problem here. Have you solved it?

Comment: @spartygw nope(.

Comment: Well that's disappointing. I have to figure this out so I'll report back here when I do.

Comment: @spartygw have you figured it out? I have the same problem

Comment: @Shongsu sorry to say no. My solution is to find a way to get out of electron. It's just not well supported.

Comment: @spartygw Did you find any solutions because I also having same issue.

Comment: @HardikKothari sorry but no. I'm hoping that WebView eventually catches up to chrome and I can dump electron.